# Proof: let $f:A \to B$ with $f$ bijective, then $f{\restriction_{C} }: C \to B$ is bijective

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra

I need the proof of following:

"let $f:A \to B$ with $f$ bijective, then $f{\restriction_{C} }: C \to B$ is bijective"

Thanks in advance

Comment: If $C\subset A$ then this may be wrong by losing the surjectivity. I guess you want to prove that the restriction is injective which is more or less obvious.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $\,f{\restriction_C}:C\to f(C)\,$?

Comment: Hi @YACP, in fact I thought same thing... the injection is simple... thank yuo soo much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction to f is not bijective unless $A=C$ for any  f which is bijective. Let $ x\in A\setminus C$

$f(x)\in B$ and $f(y)\neq f(x) $ for all $y \in C$ as f is injective.  So it's not surjective any more.

Answer (score 2):

This is false. Take $A=B=\mathbb{R}$ and $f=id$. Then restrict to $C=\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$. Then every negative real number has no more a pre-image in $C$, hence $f{\restriction_{C} }$ loses surjectivity

Comment: thanks... you proof using a counterexample... is correct?

Comment: @GarnakOlegovitc yes, if a counterexample exists, then the assertion is false in general